# Prove that a $p-$group is cyclic using the definition of centre

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Grillet's "Abstract Algebra", and in the chapter of the group actions, after proving that a nontrivial finite $p-$group has a nontrivial center, it states without proving that a group $G$ of order $p$ is cyclic.
I've already prove the statement using Lagrange's Lemma, but I was wondering if I can prove it using the center of a group: the center $Z$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and I have that the order of $Z$ is equal to $p$, but now I don't know how to continue: because now $Z(G)=G$, so $G$ is abelian, but it's not what I want to prove...any hints?

Comment: I don't think that after reading the proof that a **finite** (otherwise it may well false big time) $\;p\,-$ group has non-trivial center, nobody should have any serious problem proving that a group of order $\;p\;$ is cyclic (that's probably the reason the result was stated without proof)...and I can't think of a way of proving that with the center thingy. Proving it with Lagrange's almost trivial.

Comment: My question was more like "is there any cute centre's property which is linked with the cyclicity?" because we defined the centre without spending too much time on it... anyway, thanks for the correction, I totally forgot that hypothesis!

Comment: Since the center coincides with the group, there really isn't much you can say.